# nginx loading page very slow

Tags: nginx, performance

I just deployed nginx in a new environment with the same configuration that I've used previously and I am seeing some very odd behavior.

Nginx is configured as a reverse proxy for Solr, when I try to access the Solr UI through nginx, it takes about a minute to load. I checked Chrome dev tools and it looks like the browser is able to download 6 files right off the bat, however then all other requests are in a pending status. Then it just sits there for exactly a minute and after that everything gets downloaded and page loads. After that, the browsing is fast; I think this is mainly because of local browser cache.

Here is the config:

```
worker_processes  10;
error_log  /directory/path/error.log debug;
pid        /directory/path/nginx1.pid;

events {
     worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
 access_log  /directory/path/access.log;
 proxy_temp_path /directory/path/ 1 2;

upstream backend-test-old {
    server 1.1.1.1:7071;
    server 2.2.2.2:7071;
}

server {
    listen       7071;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log /directory/path/access_7071.log;
    proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    location /solr {
        proxy_pass http://backend-test-old;
    }
}
}
```

I also see a lot of these in the logs:

```
2015/07/10 11:06:38 [warn] 31503#0: *120 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /dir/path/7/00/0000000007 while reading upstream, client: 111.111.111.111
2015/07/10 11:06:36 [info] 31503#0: *96 client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while connecting to upstream, 
2015/07/10 11:06:36 [error] 31503#0: *101 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client:
```

Now this is not a problem on my dev server, which runs the same config and should be configured relatively similar, so it could be something system related, but I am not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

It looks like the issue is me pointing to back end hosts by IP vs hostname. I am not sure why this is an issue. I've implemented this config:

```
worker_processes  10;
error_log  /path/error.log debug;
pid        /path/nginx1.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
     access_log  /path/access.log;
     proxy_temp_path /pathproxy_temp/ 1 2;

    upstream backend-test-old {
        server hostname-for-1.1.1.1:7071;
        server hostname-for-2.2.2.2:7071;
    }

    upstream backend-test-old2 {
        server 1.1.1.1:7071;
        server 2.2.2.2:7071;
    }

    server {
        listen       7071;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log /path/access_7071.log;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
        location /solr {
                proxy_pass http://backend-test-old;
        }
    }

        server {
        listen       7072;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log /path/access_7072.log;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
        location /solr {
                proxy_pass http://backend-test-old2;
        }
    }
}
```

If I go through 7071 it works fine, however if I hit through 7072 the performance problem described above occurs. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: IS this of any help http://serverfault.com/questions/587386/an-upstream-response-is-buffered-to-a-temporary-file

Comment: Please check out the edit

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Use host names instead of ips, in upstream sections.

Comment: did you find a fix for this issue? I seem to have the exact reverse issue in that it is the hostname that causes the one minute wait and the ips that work "fast".

Answer (score 11):

The buffering causes problems there, turn it off completely:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

See [the official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering) for details:

> When buffering is disabled, the response is passed to a client
>   synchronously, immediately as it is received. nginx will not try to
>   read the whole response from the proxied server. The maximum size of
>   the data that nginx can receive from the server at a time is set by
>   the proxy_buffer_size directive.

Comment: Would this be in the individual site's config, or in nginx.conf?

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `proxy.conf` contents with the following values:

```
proxy_buffers           32 4m;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     25m;
proxy_buffer_size 512k;
proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size        1024m;
client_body_buffer_size     4m;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_intercept_errors off;
```